# Spark Application FAIR Scheduling

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a job who iterates over the a table columns to get the distinct values of each one. The queries takes about 6 seconds each one but they don't use the full CPU's. That's why I have decided to use the FAIR scheduling within an Application so the resources can be fully used. Actually this application have 4 cores and 10 Gb ram.

I have added to my spark spark-defaults.conf file the following lines:

```
spark.scheduler.mode FAIR
spark.scheduler.allocation.file /bin/spark/pools.xml
```

I have created the following pool:

```
<pool name="filters">
<schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
<weight>1000</weight>
<minShare>0</minShare>
</pool>
```

And this is my code:

```
List<ColumnMetadata> fields = getCategoryFieldsFromViewMetadata(...);
Dataset<Row> dsCube = sqlContext.sql("...");

dsCube = dsCube
        .select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(filterColumns))
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());

dsCube.createOrReplaceTempView("filter_temp");

sqlContext.sparkContext().setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "filters");

fields.parallelStream().forEach((ColumnMetadata field) -> {
    Dataset<Row> temp = sqlContext.sql("select distinct tenant_id, user_domain, cube_name, field, value "
                        +"from filter_temp");
    saveDataFrameToMySQL("analytics_cubes_filters", temp, SaveMode.Append); //Here I save the results to a MySQL table.
});
sqlContext.sparkContext().setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", null);
```

The *filters* pool is being used, I can see it in the spark application GUI and the jobs are executed in parallel, but if before, each query was executed in FIFO mode in 6 seconds now using the FAIR mode 4 parallel queries are executed in 24 seconds. I have checked the CPU usage and looks like before when the FIFO mode was being used.

Am I missing something?